# Hard disk recognised by laptop but can not copy/past data from it

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive

I had a hard disk, the main disk that came with the computer.

Due to power failure my computer shut down and the drive was not detected.

So, I replaced it.

Now I have the old drive and as I have free time and as I am interested in doing things by researching.

I opened the drive and attached it externally via a USB 2.0 connector.

- My computer is running windows 10 pro.
- The external disk is detected by the computer.
- I did not want the files so, I formatted all 3 partitions. The formatting was successful, but the partitions become raw.
- Now on researching more I applied DOS commands

  ```
  Diskpart
  List disk
  Select disk
  Detail disk
  select volume
  FORMAT RECOMMENDED OVERRIDE
  ```
- This last command is taking too long.

  [image]

If this command is successful then what do I do next?

Comment: This is obviously Windows, which cannot read/write directly to RAW partitions (RAW basically means no filesystem or unformatted) and this is a simple disk operation... why would you not just use Disk Management, delete the volumes, create a new NTFS volume, and let Windows do the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Format the HDD as NTFS. That should fix it. You can use either the Format option in the drive's File Explorer context menu, or disk part.